# Evaluate this alpha substitution $[(zx)/x] \, \lambda z.xyz$

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

I am having difficulty with the following problem: 
Calculate the result of this substitution, renaming the bound variables
as needed, so that substitution is defined

$[(zx)/x] \, \lambda z.xyz$

*Attempt:*
If I were to simply replace $x$ with $zx$ in this expression it would yield : 
$\lambda z.zxyz$ but I am not sure if this is correct. Any tips appreciated as I honestly don't even know what the question is asking because it seems to imply I should be renaming bound variables

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but maybe keep the parenthesis around $(zx)$ when it replaces the $x.$

Comment: I guess my gripe is that it just seems too simple a solution I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Since it's just substitution I'd expect it to be easy rather than involved. Disclaimer-- I'm not familiar with the lambda notation or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short answer.* 
No, the answer proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2996048/288417) is wrong. Actually, $[(zx)/x]\, \lambda z.xyz = \lambda t.(zx)yt$, which is completely different from $\lambda t.(t(zx)y)$ because application is not commutative, unlike the usual product: in general, the term $xy$ is the application of $x$ to $y$ (where $x$ and $y$ are intended as two arbitrary functions), which is different from $yx$ i.e. the application of $y$ to $x$.

Anyway, you are right when you say that $[(zx)/x]\, \lambda z.xyz \neq \lambda z.zxyz$. Indeed, substitution in the $\lambda$-calculus is not a simple replacement of something with something else, because of the problem of the *capture of variables*, which I explain below.

---

*(Very) Long answer.*

Substitution is a delicate operation in the [$\lambda$-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).
Indeed, the $\lambda$-calculus is intended as a formal system for expressing computation based on abstraction and application using variable binding and substitution, where functions are taken as *first class values*:   every term in the $\lambda$-calculus represents a (computable) function. A naïve approach in the definition of substitution in the $\lambda$-calculus may change the meaning of the represented functions in a inconsistent way.

In the syntax of the $\lambda$-calculus, the $\lambda$ is an operator binding a variable in a function. 
For instance, the term $\lambda x.x$ represents the identity function ($x \mapsto x$), the term $\lambda x. y$ represents the constant function ($x \mapsto y$, i.e. everything is mapped to $y$). Note that  the particular choice of a bound variable, in a $\lambda$, does not (usually) matter: for instance, the term $\lambda x . x$ is the same as the term $\lambda y. y$ because they both represents the identity function. Formally, terms in the $\lambda$-calculus are identified up to *[$\alpha$-equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence)*, i.e. up to renaming of the bound variables.

Now, consider the term $[x/y] \, \lambda x. y$. Morally, it represents the constant function $x \mapsto y$ (everything is mapped to $y$) where $y$ is replaced by $x$, that is, it represent the constant function $z \mapsto x$ (everything is mapped to $x$).
However, if we intended the substitution as a simple replacement, $[x/y] \, \lambda x. y$ would be $\lambda x. x$, i.e. the constant function, a completely different function from the intended one. 
The problem arises because the variable $x$ in the substitution $[x/y]$ has be *captured* by the binder $\lambda x$ in the term.
So, in order to define substitution in a consistent way, the problem of the capture of variable has to be avoided.

The solution is defining [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Capture-avoiding_substitutions) in a *capture-avoiding* way as follows: given the terms $t$ and $u$, the term $[u/x]\, t$ is obtained from $t$ by replacing the free (i.e. not bound by a $\lambda$) occurrences of $x$ in $t$ with $u$, *provided* that the bound variables of $t$ are not free in $u$; if this proviso is not fulfilled by $t$, then we work on a term $t'$ (instead of $t$) where this proviso holds: this is always possible thanks to $\alpha$-equivalence, i.e. by renaming the bound variables in $t$ (which does not change the meaning of $t$, as I explained before).
For example, in $[x/y] \, \lambda x. y$ the variable $x$ in the substitution is also a bound variable in the term $\lambda x. y$; then, instead of performing the replacement on $\lambda x. y$, we do it in the $\alpha$-equivalent term $\lambda z. y$ (or $\lambda w.y$, it is the same) and then we get $[x/y] \, \lambda x. y = \lambda z. x$ (or equivalently, $[x/y] \, \lambda x. y = \lambda w. x$).

Coming back to your question, in the term $[(zx)/x]\, \lambda z.xyz $, the term $zx$ in the substitution contains a free variable $z$ that is bound in $\lambda z.xyz $, so before performing the substitution we have to rename the term $\lambda z.xyz $ in a $\alpha$-equivalent way, say $\lambda w.xyw $ (or equivalently, $\lambda t.xyt $, if $t$ stands for a variable). Therefore, $[(zx)/x]\, \lambda z.xyz = \lambda w.(zx)yw $ (or equivalently, $[(zx)/x]\, \lambda z.xyz = \lambda t.(zx)yt $).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out what was wrong. The question is basically saying, in regular English, replace a free variable by another free variable that is the product of two free variables,
so the answer is

$\lambda t.(t(zx)y)$

Comment: No, it isn't. Actually, $[(zx)/x] \lambda z.xyz = \lambda t. (zx)yt$. Moreover, saying that $zx$ is the product of two variables is really misleading: $zx$ is the _application_ of the variable $z$ to the variable $x$. Note that the application is not commutative, unlike the usual product.

Comment: oops. Ok my bad.

Comment: Maybe you should post an answer then.

Comment: Done! Don't hesitate to ask more if it is unclear or too technical.